# Organize C# usings in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I assigned a keyboard shortcut for remove and sort usings but, I wanna know if it possible to organize usings on save or on format document?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm using [Power Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) extension to do that, as I used before on Visual Studio 2017 and it works very well.
After installing, in *Tools -> Options* you have a new *Productivity Power Tools* option that allows configuring to **Format document on save** and **Remove and Sort Usings on save**. [image: PowerCommands options]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. It may be worth adding that the reason this is relevant is because it includes options for **Format document on save** and **Remove and sort usings on save**. This will mean your answer could still help someone in the future if the link breaks, but the tool is still around.

Comment: You are right @oliver-clare, I updated my answer. Thank you for your help and feedback!

Comment: In my opinion, it's worth mentioning here that there is one more setting that affects `using`s sort (at least that's the case with _Visual Studio 2015_) — it can be found in the **Tools** » **Options** » **Text Editor** » **C#** » **Advanced** » _Using Directives_ section, checkbox: _Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings_. It's useful to check-it if you like to follow this rule: [Order and group namespaces according to the company (AV2402)](https://csharpcodingguidelines.com/layout-guidelines/#AV2402)

Comment: How to achieve this in visual studio 2022